# Why debugger breaks on variable with same name as another variable in different scope?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I have a weird bug in VS2022 and not sure how to find out why is it like that. I have a combination of if and else if blocks one after another, and if the application enters the else if block, where a variable is declared, with the same name, as a variable which is declared in the if block, then the debugger throws a Null Reference Exception on this variable. The code works fine, but VS2022 debugger doesn't work properly.
The following code is an illustrative example - here everything works, but I have the same situation in my code which I can't share.

```cs
List<Test> test = new List<Test>();
test.Add(new Test(){ part1 = "asad", part2 = "asdasd"});   
test.Add(new Test(){ part1 = "asad", part2 = "asdasd"});   
test.Add(new Test(){ part1 = "asad", part2 = "asdasd"});   

bool check1 = false;
bool check2 = true;

if(check1)
{
    var parts = test.Where(x => x.part1.StartsWith("a"));
}
else if(check2)
{
    var parts = test.Where(x => x.part1.StartsWith("a"));
}
```

In my code, if I was to rename the second variable to parts2, then the debugger properly shows it's content.
What could be causing this situation?

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you definitely debugging a DEBUG build and not a RELEASE build?

Comment: the reasons for NREs are plentyful. As the code is working in your prod-environment, I guess your actual data has some null-elements somewhere. Make sure your code matches the assembly being executed. Despite this there's not much we can take for sure here, as with the above code NREs are impossible.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, I can confirm that, the app is run as Debug Any CPU

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain what does NRE mean?

Comment: Aaa, sorry, a NullReferenceException

Comment: Have you checked in your debugger the values for `test`and `x`?

Comment: So, you are breaked in the `else if`, after `parts` has been assigned, and inspecting `parts` results in a NRE?

Comment: @JonasH in my code yes, I put a breakpoint after parts have been assigned, and inspecting parts results in a NRE.

Comment: That seem to work fine for me using VS 17.7.0. It could be a bug in the debugger. If updating VS do not help, try to characterize the problem as much as possible and report it.

Comment: _"throws a Null Reference Exception on this variable"_ how did you know it throws on a variable? Can you show a screenshot of the debugger break or a [mre]?

Comment: Your sample code  was debugged fine at my side(VS 17.7.4) without NullReferenceException. Could you share the screenshots of  the watch window including the parts variable and sample code of class Test to help us better understand this scenario ?

Comment: @DouXu-MSFT as I have stated in my question - this is an example of what I have in my code (which I can't share) and it works. Same situation in my code doesn't work.

Comment: Hi @TK-421, ok, get it. Did you encounter an error message like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4XOW.png) in the variable parts line when you were debugging? Please  print the variable parts and check if its value is null. Or you can delete `bin/Debug` folder and re-debug to see if the issue persists.